# S3BotoStorage and Unit Testing

Tags: django, boto, django-testing, django-storage, django-media

I am using the `storages.backends.s3boto.S3BotoStorage` for my `DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE` in a Django project.

Ideally I would like to either use the default `FileSystemStorage` during unit tests or perhaps create a temporary bucket that is deleted on the conclusion of the tests.

What is the best way to accomplish this?

Answer (score 3):

I typically keep a separate settings file for tests, `test.py`. You can configure the storage backend there, as well as any other settings you want to change during tests. Then, run the tests like this:

```
python manage.py tests --settings=project.test
```

The `--settings` flag is the dotted path the the settings module you want to use (The default would be `project.settings`).

Good optimizations for a test settings file: https://web.archive.org/web/20180204071529/http://www.daveoncode.com/2013/09/23/effective-tdd-tricks-to-speed-up-django-tests-up-to-10x-faster/

[Two Scoops of Django](http://twoscoopspress.org/) is a good place to read about the multi-settings file setup.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, use separate file for testing as pointed out above.

Secondly, there is a python library called moto for mocking and testing botos3.

git repository:- https://github.com/spulec/moto